# C# - If filesize is >0Kb do this, else do that

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I am currently trying to check a files size, if it is 0Kb do xxxx, else do yyyyyyyyyy

I currently only have a batch alternative:

```
FOR /F "usebackq" %%A IN ('%file%') DO set size=%%~zA

if %size% LSS %maxbytesize% (
    TIMEOUT /T 1 
) ELSE (
    start "" "alert.bat"
)
```

Could someone demonstrate this in C# please

Comment: This is your third question in this general area in the past hour or so. Please consider reading the [faq] and also [ask] for your future questions. Generally speaking, it seems you need to seek out the documentation and a few good books or blogs.

Comment: I merely post it for your benefit. There is an algorithm in place that can eventually block you from asking questions if the system deems your questions are historically not well written or not useful to the community. Beyond that, there are other rules in place that limit the quantity of questions you can ask in a day or month. If you have a limited number you can ask, make them count. As an aside, I neither downvoted the question nor voted to close.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use the [Length](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.length.aspx) property on the [FileInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.aspx) class:

```
FileInfo file = new FileInfo("myfile.dat");
if (file.Length > 0)
{
    // do xxx
}  
else
{
    // do yyyyyyyyyy
}
```

Comment: I like how our answers are almost line-for-line identical. :)

Comment: @Sven, yes, though I have respected the OP's comments and you forgot a `;` :-)

Comment: What missing `;`? I don't see any. :P

Answer (score 2):

```
FileInfo info = new FileInfo("somefile");
if( info.Length > 0 )
{
    // Do something
}
else
{
    // Do something else
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this one helps you out!

```
using System;
using System.IO;

class Program {
    static void Main() {
        // The name of the file
        const string fileName = "test.txt";

        // Create new FileInfo object and get the Length.
        FileInfo f = new FileInfo(fileName);
        long size = f.Length;

        if(size == 0) {
            /* do something */
        } else {
            /* do something */
        }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        FileStream file = File.Open("C:\\Users\\bkrupa\\Desktop\\new.txt", FileMode.Open);

        if (file.Length == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Empty");
        }

        Console.Read();
```